# matlab nonlinear ODE with complex conjugate of the function itself

Tags: matlab, ode

I have this nonlinear first order ODE that can be simplified into

y'(t) = (-i + y*conj(y) )*y + g(t)

where i = sqrt(-1) and g(t) is some given function of t.

conj(y) is the complex conjugate of y(t).

y(t) is the function I'm looking for, but I have no idea what to do with this equation because of the conj(y), does anyone know hoe to solve this in MATLAB?

Thank in advance!

edit: t is real.

Comment: How about splitting into real and imaginary parts, solving them separately?

Comment: You mean solving two equations?  ok.. but then what does y*conj(y) become?

Does it look like
a'(t) = (-i + a^2) *a + Re(g(t)) ;
b'(t) = (-i) *b + Im(g(t))
or is this wrong?

Comment: I posted an answer, since it's too long story for comments

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to separate imaginary and real parts.

Let `y(t)=A(t)*exp(i*f(t))`, where `A(t), f(t)` are real functions, amplitude and phase correspondingly, and `i` is imaginary unity.

Then,substituting (and using `y*conj(j)=A^2`):

```
(A'+A*i*f')*exp(i*f)=(-i+A^2)A*exp(i*f)+g(t)
```

Now, if your `g(t)` is real-valued function, you get 2 equations for real functions `A,f`:

```
A'*cos(f)=(A^3)*cos(f)+g(t)
A*f'*sin(f)=-A*sin(f)
```

If `g` is complex function, separate real and imaginary parts as well.